# Getting the current directory where the script is executed as opposed to the current executing directory of the script

Tags: powershell, psake

I want to get the current directory where the script is executed as opposed to the current executing directory of the script.

The script lives in 'd:\projects\code\development.tools' and I want the directory of the project that lives in 'd:\projects\code\development\ace\ace.testing'

Now, here is the thing when I do 'Write-Host $Env:PWD' or just '$Env:PWD' outside to Psake Properties I actually get what I want but when I try to get it from within the Properties it returns what $PWD returns and that is the executing directory of the script.

```
Write-Host $Env:PWD # returns d:\projects\code\development\ace\ace.testing

Properties {
    $baseDir = $Env:PWD # returns d:\projects\code\development\.tools
}
```

I'm not sure what's happening here but I can't figure it out.

I tried to store the correct path in a variable but it didn't really work.

**UPDATE:**

After spending few hours on that I realized it's actually working! I was working on that script on and off and put a throw statement somewhere and forgot that it's there! so I thought Psake is doing something weird and because of that it doesn't work but yeah Psake is pure! ;)

So if you want to get the current directory in which the script is being executed $Env:PWD seems to do it! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the location of the script being executed:

```
Split-Path $myInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

To get the path of the present working directory:

```
(Get-Item -Path '.\' -Verbose).FullName
```

Comment: It doesn't, that's what I'm getting 'D:\projects\code\.tools'.

Comment: Oooh...I was confused. I thought you were getting PWD but wanted the script location

Comment: Got it! I did something silly, $Env:PWD is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours on that I realized it's actually working! I was working on that script on and off and put a throw statement somewhere and forgot that it's there!

So if you want to get the current directory in which the script is being executed $Env:PWD seems to do it! :)

Comment: Don't think this is universal. I'm using the new pwsh 7.0 and $Env:PWD returns null. Pretty new machine too. @EBGreen's answer works best.

Comment: @ConnorLow Thanks, I changed the accepted answer even though for my use-case it worked.